# Does the Insignia of Claws magic item work with a druid in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, wild-shape

A friend and I want to know if the [*insignia of claws*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/insignia-of-claws) magic item (HotDQ, p. 94) will work when he is in his Wild Shape form. He is playing a druid (Circle of the Moon). It does say that it affects natural weapons, but we aren't sure if Wild Shape will allow him to "wear" this item in different forms. If so, how would it be attached? Is it like a necklace, or a pin? Would it only work on specific forms?

His favorite forms are polar bear and water elemental.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a related question that gives a good answer but I can't find it.

Answer (score 10):

**It would work while Wild Shaped, if you transform into a creature your DM sees as suitable.**

As it is only an insignia, it could be attached to a cloak that should be able to be worn in most forms. It would depend on your DM, however, as the PHB states under Wild Shape:

> Worn equipment functions as normal, but the DM decides whether it is practical for the new form to wear a piece of equipment, based on the creature’s shape and size.

If the DM allows it on a cloak that remains worn, the bonus would affect your attacks as they use natural weapons. But if they rule it wouldn't be feasible to be worn (such as if you transformed into a wasp), it will be merged in and no bonus will apply.

Comment: Wouldn't some sort of a choker / collar work better than the cloak?

Comment: @Mołot Choker/collar would likely work better when going smaller (as long as it's still narrower than your head), but going bigger presents the same problem of breaking it hulk-style.

Answer (score 0):

**As long as you can wear it in Wildshape, yes**

PHB pg. 67 states:

> Your **equipment doesn't change size or shape to match the new form**, and any Equipment that the new form can't wear must either fall to the ground or merge with it. **Equipment that merges with the form has no effect until you leave the form.**

This means if you can wear the insignia while wildshaped then yes, It would still apply. Otherwise, It would do nothing.